# Why are the tables in my unidirectional @ManyToOne relationship not joining on Spring Data findAll() query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

I have a simple database with **Universities** and **Students** (see entities below)

## University.java

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "university")
public class University {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "university_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "university_name")
    private String name;

    public University() {
    }

    public University(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

## Student.java

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "student_name")
    private String studentName;

    @JoinColumn(name="university_name")
    private String studentUniversityName;

    @ManyToOne
    private University university;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String name, String studentUniversityName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.studentUniversityName = studentUniversityName;
    }
}
```

My entities should join on the `university_name` column. I wrote the following unit test to verify this behavior.

```
    @Test
    void test1() {
        final String UNIVERSITY_NAME = "U of A";

        universityRepository.save(new University(UNIVERSITY_NAME));

        studentRepository.save(new Student("Joe", UNIVERSITY_NAME));

        Student joe = studentRepository.findAll().get(0);
        assertNotNull(joe.getUniversity()); // <------ FAILING
    }
```

It is failing the `assertNotNull(joe.getUniversity())` statement, which seems to indicate that the tables did not join. The strange thing to me, is that the next test passes (when I explicity set the University on Joe. (The contents of the database are the same either way, but `findAll()` for this test seems to properly trigger a join

```
  @Test
    void test2() {
        final String UNIVERSITY_NAME = "U of A";

        University uni = new University(UNIVERSITY_NAME);
        universityRepository.save(uni);

        Student joe1 = new Student("Joe", UNIVERSITY_NAME);
        joe1.setUniversity(uni);
        studentRepository.save(joe1);

        Student student = studentRepository.findAll().get(0);
        assertNotNull(student.getUniversity());
    }
```

I don't want to set the university on Joe (like in the second test) before I save him, because sometimes I want to save students and universities at different times in the code. I want to be able to save Joe with a null university and populate the field in the call to `findAll()`

#### Can someone help me modify my entities so that the first test can pass?

Comment: You have not specified the relation between Student and University with @ManyToOne will based on which column.

Comment: You should set the University object to Student object otherwise the relationship will not establish. There is no other way around. It is required to populate the foreign key column in your database

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
public class Student {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "student_id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "student_name")
private String studentName;
private String studentUniversityName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="studentUniversityName" , 
 referencedColumn="name")    
private University university;

public Student() {
}

public Student(String name, String studentUniversityName) {
    this.name = name;
    this.studentUniversityName = studentUniversityName;
}
}

public class University {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "university_id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "university_name")
private String name;


public University() {
}

public University(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Why do I need to specify `@OneToMany` in the other entity? I only need a one-way relationship, I don't need to access students from the university object. Also, I agree that the `studentUniversityName` seems redundant, but I actually need that field for other parts of the code to function.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use id for joining, for example:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "university_id")
private University university;
```

i hope working :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I agree that IDs are generally better, but I have to use the university name in this case.